# Error when importing hooks from an npm dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, react-hooks

I am trying to import a react custom hook from one of my npm dependencies but I keep running into this error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@openmrs/openmrs-form-engine-lib/src/hooks/useConcepts' in '/Users/jamiearodi/Documents/GitHub/openmrs-esm-form-builder/src/components/interactive-builder'. The package exists in my package.json file under dependencies.

'''
import { useConcepts } from "@openmrs/openmrs-form-engine-lib/src/hooks/useConcepts";
'''

Comment: Look at what's in your node_modules, do you have `useConcepts` exported there somewhere?